# Material turns black through Glass material (Internal)

Tags: materials, blender-internal-render-engine

I am using this Glass material (http://www.blender-materials.com/material/glass-cg001) for this model here.

The thing is, the yellow color of the Diffuse material on the base of the model turns black when rendered:

[image: Error caused by glass]
  [image: What it needs to look like]

I have little to no experience in designing materials in Blender Internal. How do I go about fixing this?

Comment: Try to change the yellow material to receive transparent shadows.

Comment: that did not work.

Comment: I just tested that with the material in your link, and it solved the issue with the shadow.

Comment: Try to check it through camera view, viewport shows some black artifacts in different view distance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To enable shadows from objects with transparency you need to enable **Receive Transparent** in Shadow section in material tab.

[image]